# Creating json keys on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to create a `json` object to send as a post array, but I need to create the key on the fly

```
var id = $('#myInput').val();

var post = {
    'product[123]': 'myValue',     // this works fine - but isn't dynamic
    'product['+id+']': 'myValue'   // this does not work
}
```

Sending it in as a string works fine, but I get an issue when I want to make it more dynamic. Am I missing something really simple here, or am I trying to do something Javascript isn't supposed to do?

Comment: It is just "Object", not "JSON object".

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920930/how-to-create-json-by-javascript-for-loop ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*(Note that this has nothing to do with JSON. You're not using JSON there, you're using an [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). [JSON](http://json.org) is a textual (not code) format, which is a **subset** of JavaScript's object initializer syntax.)*

Do it outside the object initializer, using `[]` notation:

```
var id = $('#myInput').val();

var post = {};
post[product[id]] = 'myValue';
```

That will take the value (at runtime) of `product[id]` and use that as the key for the property. If you wanted the key to *literally* be `product[123]` when `id` is `123`, you'd use this instead:

```
post['product[' + id + ']'] = 'myValue';
```

A more generic discussion:

```
var a = "foo";
var obj = {};
obj[a] = "bar";
console.log(obj.foo); // "bar"
```

JavaScript allows you to specify property keys in two ways: Using dotted notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string doesn't have to be a string literal, it can be the result of any expression.

Comment: I interpreted the question as him literally wanting an attribute called `product[123]`, but the question isn't clear at all...

Comment: @Matt: I see your interpretation, thanks. I wouldn't have read it that way, but now you've pointed it out... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
post['product[' + id + ']'] = 'myValue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use '[ ]' in ids of the object? Avoid to do this.
In your sample, you can do this by the following code:

```
var id = $('#myInput').val();
var post = {
    '123': 'myValue',    
    id: 'myValue' 
}
```

Or, if you realy realy want to use an arrry (actually, all objects ARE array in JavaScript).
You can write this:

```
var product=[];
product['123']='something';
product[id]='another';
```

Comment: This will create an object (`post`) with an attribute `123` and an attribute `id` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sH38n/)). Furthermore, there's nothing wrong with him using `[]` in the name of an attribute.

Comment: Your code creates an object with the property names `123` and `id`. It does **not** use the value of the `id` variable.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is an object, not the other way round; it is not true that all objects are arrays.

Comment: doesn't use the value of id? then what is the property name of the object ?

Comment: @Jerry: See http://jsfiddle.net/sH38n/1/. It's `id`. You only need to quote a key in an Object Literal if it is a reserved word, or includes operators like `-`, `+` etc.

Comment: to Matt: everything is a object, this is very commonsense that we should not say it at all. But, I said every object in JS is a array, a "named array", you can use [ ] to get all its members.

Comment: @Jerry: That's merely [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) over dot notation. In JavaScript terminology an array is zero-indexed and has a `.length` property and is constructed via either `new Array` or `[]`. There's no concept of a `named array`, and it's use in terminology is [very misleading.](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: the value of id is not used in my first code, I made a mistake here. About object as association array, I don't see any misleading. It is just another sytax for member access operator.