# how to reformat this javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have variable like this

```
var item = [
            {'id': '1', 'quantity': '100'},
            {'id': '2', 'quantity': '200'}
        ];
```

but i need to change like this format

```
var new_item = {
            '1': {'quantity': '100'},
            '2': {'quantity': '200'}
        };
```

i do loop like this, but errors

```
for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
            new_item = {
                item[i].id: {'quantity': item[i].quantity}
            };
        }
```

how can i change this format T__T

> UPDATE FIX:

oh yes i just need to change like this

```
for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
            new_item[item[i].id] = {'quantity': item[i].quantity};
        }
```

that work, sorry for my damn question, i think i'm too sleepy, thx guys ^_^

Comment: That is not JSON (which is a serialization format).  That is simply a javascript array of objects.

Comment: Objects have **string** keys, not numeric keys.

Comment: "but errors"?? You should share your experience of these errors.

Comment: You're replacing `new_item` on every single iteration of your loop.

Comment: Take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920930/how-to-create-json-by-javascript-for-loop

Comment: ok this case done, sorry for my junk question LoL ^_^ thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation to set derived keys.  Initialize `new_item = {}` first.

```
new_item[item[i].id] = {quantity: item[i].quantity}
```

Note that if you were using ECMAScript6 you can use [computed property names in object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) like so;

```
new_item = {
    [item[i].id]: {quantity: item[i].quantity}
}
```

**However**, this overwrites `new_item` each time so it would ultimately only have the last value of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
    new_item[item[i].id] = {'quantity': item[i].quantity};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you don't need IE 8 support:

```
var newItem = item.reduce(function (o, c) {
    o[c.id] = c.quantity;
    return o;
}, {});
```